# Copy XML while excluding parent nodes, removing specific child nodes, and overwriting some child nodes

Tags: xslt, insert, copy, parent-child

I've reviewed several posts doing these things separately, but have yet to combine them all together successfully.

I have an input similar to this structure:

```
 <Response>
    <Confirmation>Success</Confirmation>
    <SecondResponse>
       <InquiryResponse>
          <ID>99999</ID>
          <Confirmation>Success</Confirmation>
          <Exception/>
          <!-- The following structure repeats a varying amount of times -->
          <DataNode1>
             <!-- Child nodes could be null, transform should remove null nodes -->
             <Child1>data</Child1>
             ...
             <Childn>dataN</Childn>
          </DataNode1>
          ...
          <DataNodeN>
             <Child1>data</Child1>
             ...
             <Childn>dataN</Childn>
          </DataNodeN>
       </InquiryResponse>
    </SecondResponse>
 </Response>
```

Now, I need to accomplish the following things:

1) Copy all children nodes of `<InquiryResponse>` (but NOT `<InquiryResponse>` itself)

2) Exclude the `<Confirmation>` and `<Exception>` nodes

3) Exclude any null children in the DataNode

4) Insert a new child element in the DataNode

So the desired output would look like this:

```
 <ID>99999</ID>
 <DataNode1>
   <Child1>data</Child1>
   <ChiildInsert>newData</ChildInsert>
   <Childn>dataN</Childn>
 </DataNode1>
 ...
 <DataNodeN>
    <Child1>data</Child1>
    <ChildInsert>newData</ChildInsert>
    <Childn>dataN</Childn>
 </DataNodeN>
```

I believe I have to do this by creating a template for each DataNode (I know all the possible values that could occur), and templates to remove the nodes I don't want and then apply them all to a master copy template that ignores null nodes. This is my current incarnation of the XSLT, using 2.0 - although I know it's not entirely complete, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- Remove Unwanted Nodes -->
  <xsl:template match='Confirmation|Exception'/>

  <!-- DataNode Template -->
  <template match='DataNode1'>
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       <ChildInsert>
          <xsl:value-of select='newData'/>
       </ChildInsert>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match='@*|node()'> 
    <xsl:if test='. != ""'>
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output I'm producing using Saxon-PE 9.3.0.5

```
 <Response>
   <SecondResponse>
     <InquiryResponse>
         <ID>99999</ID>
         <DataNode1>
            <Child1>data</Child1>
            <ChiildInsert>newData</ChildInsert>
            <Childn>dataN</Childn>
         </DataNode1>
         ....
         <DataNodeN>...</DataNodeN>
     </InquiryResponse>
   </SecondResponse>
 </Response>
```

Obviously, I'm still getting getting all the response Parents as I haven't specified a method to deal with them; however, whenever I try matching the template to the XPath, I get the data, not the XML. I know I could pass it through another transformation that just copies the child nodes of `<InquiryResponse>`, but I felt there should be more elegant way to do it instead.  Below are the problems/questions I'm still facing.

1) Since using a template like this: `<xsl:template match='Response'/>` would null my entire response, I tried switching the identify template to match `Response/SecondResponse/InquiryResponse/*` but the result only produces text data, not XML.

2) When the `<Exception>` node is populated with a value, it continues to be copied instead of removed like the `<Confirmation>` node.

3) If I wanted to update the value of a child node that isn't null, would I do it like this? There's an additional requirement to update some of the children nodes, so I'm still thinking about how to do and this seems like the correct method, but I would like to verify.

```
 <xsl:template match='childNodeA'>
     <childNodeA>
        <xsl:value-of select='someValue/>
     </childNodeA>
 </xsl:template>
```

I apologize if this is unclear, but feel free to request any further details you made need and a tremendous thank you in advance for anyone who can assist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output XML you posted is not well-formed since it has no root element, but this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet should do what you want:

**Stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Apply all child nodes; don't copy the element itself -->
  <xsl:template match="Response | SecondResponse | InquiryResponse">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Drop elements -->
  <xsl:template match="Confirmation | Exception"/>

  <xsl:template match="DataNode1 | DataNode2 | DataNodeN">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Apply Child1, ignore children with no text content -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Child1[normalize-space(.)]"/>
      <!-- Insert new element -->
      <ChildInsert>newData</ChildInsert>
      <!-- Apply all other child elements except Child1 -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[normalize-space(.)][not(self::Child1)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input**:

```
<Response>
  <Confirmation>Success</Confirmation>
  <SecondResponse>
     <InquiryResponse>
        <ID>99999</ID>
        <Confirmation>Success</Confirmation>
        <Exception/>
        <!-- The following structure repeats a varying amount of times -->
        <DataNode1>
           <!-- Child nodes could be null, transform should remove null nodes -->
           <Child1>data</Child1>
           <Childn>dataN</Childn>
        </DataNode1>
        <DataNodeN>
           <Child1>data</Child1>
           <Childn>dataN</Childn>
        </DataNodeN>
     </InquiryResponse>
  </SecondResponse>
</Response>
```

**Output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ID>99999</ID>
<DataNode1>
  <Child1>data</Child1>
  <ChildInsert>newData</ChildInsert>
  <Childn>dataN</Childn>
</DataNode1>
<DataNodeN>
  <Child1>data</Child1>
  <ChildInsert>newData</ChildInsert>
  <Childn>dataN</Childn>
</DataNodeN>
```

Note that since you didn't specify what "null" means, I assumed it to mean elements without text content. So the code above would drop a `<Child1>` element like this:

```
<Child1>
  <GrandChild1/>
</Child1>
```

Comment: Correct, a "null" node would be a node without text. i.e. <Nullnode/>. Thank you for the response, I'll be testing it shortly!

Comment: This is almost perfect. I'm still getting the SecondResponse and Inquiry Response Nodes, and I'm still running into the issue where if the Exception node has text, it's still being copied. Any ideas are to how I may trouble shoot those items?  Thanks again!

Comment: Are you using the exact XSLT stylesheet and input document I pasted? Because if you are, I'll be really surprised if you're still experiencing those problems. I tried with `xsltproc` and Saxon 9.1.0.5J and it works as expected with both processors. On the other hand, if either your stylesheet or input document are somehow different, I won't be able to help without seeing them. By the way, I can't reproduce the problem with the `Exception` node with your original stylesheet, either.

Comment: My input is slightly different, but same structure. My actual exception is "GAException" but I know to change the values in my xslt. I modified the identity transform slightly to say "apply-templates select='@* | node()[name() != 'Exception']'"
and that worked fine. Although I couldn't find an elegant way to remove the 2 responses, but I can still work with that data. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: As a bonus, lets say that there were namespaces used at various node, how could we exclude them using this template. I have been other templates, that use "local-name" but I'm not sure how to combine that with this one.  Just a thought, not a requirement. Thanks again